# How to use video capture object outside the main function in this code?

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to use video capture object outside the main function for making my program .The code is incorrect .
Something like this:

```
class Abc{
        void frameDetails(int width = 640,int height =480){
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    cv::VideoCapture cap(0);
    Abc obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to include a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a constructor to your class which will open the `cv::VideoCapture` object. The `cap` object can be a public variable.

```
class Abc
    {
        cv::VideoCapture cap;
        Abc(){
        cap.open(0);
        }
        void frameDetails(int width = 640,int height =480){
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,width);
        cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,height);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    Abc obj();
    return 0;
}
```

I haven't tested this code, but this is logically how you can achieve this.